# How to remove integers from strings

Tags: python

I would like to take a list containing integers in strings and remove those integers.
Example:

```
    list = ["1. car","2. laptop","3. phone","4. monitor"]
```

Becomes:

```
    list = ["car","laptop","phone","monitor"]
```

Comment: Two steps:   First, define a function that converts a single string, possibly containing a number, call it "deNumber(s)".   Then you can use a list comprehension to say "result = [ deNumbers(s) for s in list_of_strings ]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using list comprehension with `re.sub()`:

```py
import re

lst = ["1. car", "2. laptop", "3. phone", "4. monitor"] # avoid using list as a variable name, as list is a built-in function.

output = [re.sub(r'\d+\. ', '', x) for x in lst]
print(output) # ['car', 'laptop', 'phone', 'monitor']
```

The regex can be (or must be) modified according to your full data.

Answer (score 1):

The `.isalpha()` method can be used:

```
from string import digits

new_list = [''.join(x for x in i if x.isalpha()) for i in list]
```

Comment: Do you mean isalpha() in your title

Answer (score 1):

If your the numbers in your strings are always at the start and followed by a period and a space, you can do it using the split method:

```
L = ["1. car","2. laptop","3. phone","4. monitor"]

L = [s.split(". ",1)[-1] for s in L]

print(L) # ['car', 'laptop', 'phone', 'monitor']
```